# Relaunch iPhone Simulator for each test from Suite

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unit-testing, ui-testing

Is it possible to configure Xcode in such a way so when I run all of my test each one will be performed on a "new iPhone Simulator". I'm testing UI related stuff and I want each test to start on a newly opened application.

Currently, application is starting only once and all of the tests are starting one after another and sometimes the ending state after one test is not good for the next test to start.

**Solved**

I used XCTool (https://github.com/facebook/xctool)

I was able to run one particulatr test by invoking command:

```
xctool  -workspace WorkspaceName.xcworkspace -scheme Workspace -sdk iphonesimulator run-tests -only TestTarget:TestClass/test_Some_Method
```

Then I simply wrote a script to run all of the tests I had. This way every test triggers simulator to run application once again from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You could, before the next test, delete the app as you would do it in a real iPhone.